# How do i change url based put mapping to body based put mapping in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here how can i map my path variables to entity

```
    @PutMapping("/editExperience/{id}/{year}/{icon}")
    public void editExperience(@PathVariable long id,@PathVariable int year,@PathVariable String icon)
    {
        profileService.editExperience(id,year,icon);
    }
```

I tried using a  requestbody in the field as well but its not working

Comment: question is ambiguous. more details would certainly help users understand the exact issue

Comment: try @PathVariable("id") @PathVariable("year") @PathVariable("icon")

Comment: I have to use some class of entity instead of @PathVariable

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a DTO.

```java
public class ExperienceDTO {
 //add fields
 //generate getters and setters or use lombok
}
```

Change your API

```
@PutMapping("/editExperience/{id}")
public void editExperience(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody ExperienceDTO experienceDTO)
{
     //in service class, use object mapper to map dto 
    //to entity or make use of map struct 
    //or simple setter methods after fetching the entity from DB using findById(id);
    profileService.editExperience(id, experienceDTO);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a body, you can use `@RequestBody`.
You need a class such as EditExperience with the variables int id, int year and String icon (for example).

Also, in your controller add `@RequestBody EditExperience editExperience` instead of your `@PathVariable` code. Now you can call your endpoint with put and a json such as:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "year": 2023,
    "icon": test123
}
```

Another possibility without the path variables would be using form-data.